# 'This is not what you think' Is there any way to frame this sentence without using 'not' or any other words meaning the same

Tags: sentence

You would need to come up with sentences meaning the same as this without actually using not or similar words/synonyms and actually the sentence shouldn't be showing any negative vibes or emotion

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It was like a challenge from my sibling,an psychologist who wants to counsel an patient and needs to use this sentence..but she doesn't wanna display any negative outlook or emotions towards him as hes seriously depressed

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more (by editing the original question) on what "counts" as "similar words"? I mean, if the question is "can you negate a sentence without negating it," then it becomes a serious challenge of rhetoric. If it's simply "can you avoid words that are excessively negative," that's different.

Comment: Oh, also please edit to make just a little clearer exactly what meaning is intended. "This is not what you think" is often something someone says when caught in a comically compromising position—"this isn't what it looks like." It sounds like you're going instead for a more nuanced "your outlook on this scenario is subjective, and the reality is different" idea.

Comment: This is different from what you think.

Answer (score 2):

A person uttering *This is not what you think* presumably knows what the other person is (likely) thinking and should be able to reformulate the contradiction as:

> You may be thinking this is _____; however, it is really/just/merely _____ .

or

> You may be thinking this is _____, but isn't it really/just/merely _____ ?

Rather than contradicting the thought by saying only what something *isn't*, the therapist can state the (presumably) less serious/disturbing (or more accurate) reality of what it *is*, drawing the patient's attention away from the erroneous thought by offering a more realistic/appropriate alternative. In addition, the reformulation gives the patient a chance to confirm or correct that therapist's assumption.

Comment: In a therapeutic context, it can also be helpful to validate the subjective perception before offering the alternative: "I hear that you're thinking this is ___, and I can see how you'd feel that way. I think if you ___, though, you can see that it's ____."

Comment: “Let me offer another perspective.” “Here’s another way to think about it.  What if . . .”

Comment: Positivity 101: Don't say something and then follow it with *but* or *however*.